# VSCode and Jupyter notebook - changes in python script code dont update

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When I write a code in the editor in VScode and then I try to import this code into jupyter notebook, the alterations I made in the code are do not update - the code that runs in jupyter notebook is the code that is open when I initialize VScode.

To update the code I need to restart VScode, open jupyter notebook, and import the code with the alterations made before restarting VScode. I set the path to the folder, and I using the same virtual environment. Is there anyway to fix this?

[image: my screen]

Comment: you edit in vs code different file since notebook have 'ipnyb' extension and normal script python have 'py' extention so it make sense it does not update

Comment: Thanks by the answer, I understand the problem, and how I can link this two windows, do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download script file from jupyter as "py" file and run it on other editors most jupyter support that for example in anaconda jupyter [image: jupyter anaconda]

and google colab support this too
but a notebook run only with program support python notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Try the autoreload magic method.
Above the import statement put this.

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Note that `%autoreload 2` means that all modules will be reimported, if you want to specify which ones to reload then use `%autoreload 1` and import using `%aimport` instead of `import`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using VScode there is an easy way to restart your Jupyter Kernel.
click the next buttons:
[image]